# Pass variables to another php page using a button

Tags: php, html

So if someone is logged in my script reads the values and stores it and sets it as variables then I'm trying to make a registration page for something that members can register in. 
The script is simple

```
     <div id="english1"><p id="english1p">تأكد من بياناتك ثم اضغط رز الموافقة</p><br>
     <form class="register2" action="includes/register2.inc.php" method="post" name="register2form"
     <p class="username">اسم المستخدم: <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?></p>
     <p class="email">الايميل: <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['email']); ?></p>
     <p class="age">السن: <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['age']); ?></p>
     <p class="coursetype">الكورس المراد التسجيل فيه: <?php echo $coursename; ?></p>
     <p class="paymethod">طرق الدفع:</p><ol><li>طريقة</li>
                                          <li>طريقة</li>
                                          <li>طريقة</li>
                                      </ol>
                                      <p class="sure">للتأكيد اضغط تسجيل</p>
     <input class="register2button"
            type="button"
            value="تسجيل" 
            onclick="" />
     </div>
```

Ignore the letters you don't understand, it's arabic.

So the script reads variables and then I want when the member clicks the submit button, the page `POST` the variables to `includes/register2.inc.php` without input as the variables are already set.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your `<p>` tags you can store all the variables you want to pass to the next page in `<input type="hidden" value="some value" />` These boxes will not be shown on the page, but will pass along data with any request you send to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `form`, instead of `p` you should use `input` for each parameter:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>"/>
```

You can kept this input hidden also like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="yourvalue"/>
```

These `input` field value won't pass in next page in `$_POST` if you will use `p` you have to use `input` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your value in hidden element and pass it to next page.

```
<form action="page name" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>" />
   <p class="username"> username : <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?></p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```